# How to specify child tags with findall using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to get only specific tag next to other tag. so if I do

`soup.findAll('blockquote')` I will get a list of all the blockquotes but I only want blockquote that also next to a tag with name attr.  `<a name="*">`

so my list of blockquotes would not contain something like this:

```
   <blockquote>
     <i>Intro </i>
  </blockquote>
```

When I only want

```
<blockquote><a name="*">  </blockquote>
```

Here below is example , but there are some other blockquote, with other inner tag. but I only want ones with `<a name="*">` inner tag.

```
<blockquote>
<i>Intro </i>
</blockquote>, <blockquote>
<a name="1">a </a><br>
</br></blockquote>, <blockquote>
<a name="2">x </a><br>
<a name="3">y </a><br>
<a name="4">z </a><br>
</br></br></br></blockquote>
```

well, altermately I want the result I want to get something like this

```
<blockquote>
    <a name="1">a </a><br>
    </br></blockquote>, <blockquote>
    <a name="2">x </a><br>
    <a name="3">y </a><br>
    <a name="4">z </a><br>
    </br></br></br></blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can do it *in one go* with a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "blockquote" and tag.a)
```

where `tag.a` is equivalent to `tag.find("a")`.

In other words, this would find all `blockquote` elements that have an `a` child element.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting all the `a` tags that are direct children of `blockquote` tags and then getting their parents (blockquotes)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<blockquote>
<i>Intro </i>
</blockquote>, <blockquote>
<a name="1">a </a><br>
</br></blockquote>, <blockquote>
<a name="2">x </a><br>
<a name="3">y </a><br>
<a name="4">z </a><br>
</br></br></br></blockquote>
""", 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('blockquote > a'):
    print(a.parent)
```

Result:

```
<blockquote>
<a name="1">a </a><br>
</br></blockquote>
<blockquote>
<a name="2">x </a><br>
<a name="3">y </a><br>
<a name="4">z </a><br>
</br></br></br></blockquote>
```